# beta with a subscript as a cell value in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I write a beta with a subscript as a cell value in dataframe?

I want something like this:

[image]

So the codes go like

first_column <- c(?)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Unicode escape sequences. β is Unicode 0x03b2, and the numeric subscript block starts at 0x2080, so you can do

```r
c("\u03b2\u2080.\u2080\u2082\u2085", 
  "\u03b2\u2080.\u2085", 
  "\u03b2\u2080.\u2089\u2087\u2085")
#> [1] "β₀.₀₂₅" "β₀.₅"   "β₀.₉₇₅"
```